# How can we prevent a user from uploading a file and consuming bandwidth?

Tags: node.js, file, file-upload, multipartform-data

Scenario: My web server has limited bandwidth. A user is uploading a large file to my nodejs server. I invalidate it after realizing the size is too big.

```
req.on("data", (chunk) => {
    size += chunk.size;
    if(size > 100) {
         // how would I abort? 
    }
});
```

How would I abort the upload and not consume any further bandwidth from the user's multipart upload?

Would req.removeAllListeners() do the job in this scenario?

Comment: How about: `req.abort()`?

Comment: `req.removeAllListeners()` might stop you from listening to more data messages, but it won't necessarily stop the data from being sent and using your bandwidth.  You need to drop the connection to prevent more sending.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `multer` for file-upload, you can easily limit the file-size, by doing, something similar to:

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize }
})
```

And same can be done with `body-parser` for all other type of requests, by doing:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: maxSize}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: maxSize}));
```

And same with `raw` and `text`.